# InfoPath Designer 2010 - Format HTML tags

Tags: infopath, html, formatting

I have set up a web browser form for SP2007 in InfoPath Designer 2010.  It points to a list that contains several columns of different types, to include some enhanced rich text multiline fields.  The form's data connection is a URL that points to an XML rendering of the list items.

The problem I'm having is that when the information is imported from the list, the field also includes the surrounding HTML tags (<div>, <p>, <span>, etc.).  I'd like to keep the formatting they provide, but not display the tags-- so effectively make the SPD field render HTML.  I do not have the ability to add code to the form, so the answer, if any, must be possible through field settings.

As a follow-on question, will formatting changes made in the form be sent back to SharePoint upon submission?  That is, if I add text with bold parts, will the newly bolded text be visible in the SharePoint list?  This is desirable behavior.

Comment: What was the necessity to pull XML instead of standard list data connection?